# How to make stderr of OS commands ran with "!" go to Sql*plus spool?

Tags: shell, sqlplus, stderr, spool

### Background

I have a long **Sql*plus** script that for some reason needs to run some unix commands using the exclamation mark syntax.

I write to a spool in order to have a log file at the end of the process.

The problem is that if an OS command fails, the **stderr** is lost and doesn't go to the spooled file.

**Example code**

```
spool mylog.txt
!echo alter user xxx identified by yyyy;
alter user xxx identified by yyyy;
!echo cp file1 folder1/
!cp file1 folder1/
!echo alter user yyy identified by xxx;
alter user yyy identified by xxx;
!echo cp file2 folder2/
!cp file2 folder2/
spool off
```

If one `cp` fails, I wouldn't know just by looking at mylog.txt

Obviously doing `!cp file1 folder1/ &> mylog.txt` would only mess up the log beeing spooled to in unpredictable ways.

### Question

What can be done in order for the the stderr of the unix commands be writen to the file beeing spooled to ?

### Update

I tried [lc.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44853/lc) suggestion, appending  `2>&1`  at the end of every cp command in order to redirect stderr to stdout but I get this:

```
Enter value for 1:
```

### Update 2

`SET DEFINE OFF` made it to not prompt for a value. It allowed me to discover that it's not only stderr that doesn't get spooled: stdout doesn't either. It seems that **everything executed with "!" is un-spool-able**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the stdout and stderr are not lost but they won't go in the spool file.

Given the script `echo.sql` :

```
spool sql.out
select 1 from dual ;
!echo 1
!invalid command
spool off
```

If you launch your script from a shell as so :

```
sqlplus *connect string*  @echo.sql > host.out 2> host.err
```

You will get the output from your sql command in `sql.out`, the output from echo in `host.out` and the error message in `host.err`. If you're launching your script non interactively -from a cron or something- you'll have to capture stdout/stderr as you would do any other non sql*plus script.

**Edit** regarding comment

With the option `SET TERMOUT ON` in the script file you will have the output of your sql commands both in the spool file and stdout.

So finally, if you want everything in one file you can call your script as so :

```
sqlplus *connect string*  @echo.sql &>echo.log
```

You will still have the output of just the sql in the spool file.

Comment: The problem is that I need to generate a log. In the log the entries must be in the same order as they happened. Having sql output in a files and non-sql output in another file doesn't help me. Appending the non-sql output at the end of the same file is not a proper log either.

Comment: Your answer along with lc.'s one steered me to the solution. I will accept yours though because it's more complete and for the datailed explanation. I finally deleted the spool command from the sql file and generated the log through bash with `sqlplus *connect string*  @echo.sql 2>&1 | tee -a echo.log`. That way I can see what happens when I run it interactively, and also get a log with stderr, sdtout and Sql*plus output.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a `2>&1` to each command to redirect stderr to stdout.

Comment: I just tested it, I get prompted to `Enter value for 1: `

Comment: By the way, stdout doesn't get written to spools either.

Comment: The above should work for bash. Do you happen to know which shell `!` is using? (AFAIK, stdout is the very thing that is written to the spool, and the problem here lies in that stderr is not. Therefore the solution should be to redirect stderr to stdout)

Comment: It's Bash. The problem is sqlplus sees the &1 as a parameter, since parameters in sql scripts follow the form &1, &2 etc.

Comment: That's odd. According to [this FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.21_and_HOST.3F), `!` should not be performing variable substitution (whereas `HOST` will). You could try a `SET DEFINE OFF` to disable prompting (unless you need it elsewhere)

Comment: `SET DEFINE OFF` made it to not prompt for a value. It allowed me to discover that it's not only stderr that doesn't get spooled: stdout doesn't either. It seems that everything executed with "!" is un-spool-able.

Comment: Hmm...could you reverse the logic and write a *shell script* that calls sqlplus with SQL commands (possibly read from a script file), interspersed with regular shell commands, redirecting everything to a log file?

Comment: Maybe I will. That was my last resort.

Comment: Or if you're guaranteed sqlplus will flush the spooled file when you do `spool off`, you can do `spool off`, `!echo "blah blah" >>mylog.txt`, `!cp foo bar >>mylog.txt 2&>1`, `spool mylog.txt append`, `...`. Not sure if it will work though.

Comment: The problem is that I need to generate a log. In the log the entries must be in the same order as they happened. Having the messages of the non-sql commands appended at the end doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send shell command output to your sqlplus spool file, you can't do it while SPOOL has the file locked for writing.  Here's the sequence in the .sql script that worked for me:

SPOOL out.log

...sql stuff here...

SPOOL OFF

host ps -eaf | grep something 1>>out.log

SPOOL out.log APPEND

...more sql stuff...